# How can I easily solve$ \int \frac{-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I'm having trouble while solving $\int \:tcos^{-1}tdt$ . I used integration by parts on it and then the above integral showed up so please if you have any other easy way to do this, help me,,,

Comment: Hint: This suggests $t = \sin y.$

Comment: Can’t do what? What is the new integral?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks buddy, it helped and I got the answer easily...

Comment: Do **not** edit your post in a way that renders the existing answers irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = t$ and $dv = \frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt$. Then $du=dt$ and $v = \sqrt{1-t^2}$; so
\begin{align}
\int \frac{-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt = \int udv 
&= uv - \int vdu \\
&= \textstyle t \sqrt{1-t^2} - \displaystyle \int \textstyle \sqrt{1-t^2} dt.
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: The real problem is here, where want to solve the second integral (the negative one) i.e; $\int \sqrt{1-t^2}dt$

Comment: Here apply the change of variables $t=\sin(x)$

Comment: @SyedBilalHaider See [Trigonometric substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution).

Answer (score 1):

You want to so solve the given integral in a simple way. I suggest the following approach, where no substitution is needed.

First, modify the integral as follows:

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt
 &=\int\left(\frac{1-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)\,\mathrm dt\\[1em]
 &=\int\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt-\arcsin(t).
\end{align*}

Next, apply the integration by parts on the last integral with $u=\sqrt{1-t^2}$ and $v'=1$. Hence, $u'=\frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ and $v=t$. Consequently, we infer that

\begin{equation}
\int\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt
 =t\sqrt{1-t^2}-\int\frac{-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt.
\end{equation}

Substituting it back, we obtain

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt
 =t\sqrt{1-t^2}-\int\frac{-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt-\arcsin(t).
\end{equation}

From the last line, we can solve your integral immediately since the integral on the right-hand side is identical with the one on the left. Therefore,

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\int\frac{-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt
 =\frac12\cdot\left(t\sqrt{1-t^2}-\arcsin(t)\right)+C}.
\end{equation}